# Grouping by days

Tags: mongodb

I want to have a graph that show how many purchases was made on each day. The user should then be able to switch between showing purchases made today, last 7 days and last 30 days

Say I have a lot of these (simplfied) documents

```
purchase: {
  itemId: 'some id'
  createdAt: 'some date..'
}
```

I want to get an array of elements, each corresponding to the number of times a 'purchase' documents created on that day occurs.

I have tried fiddling around with the mongo aggregation framework, but hasnt been able to create a query that manages this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will group purchases by the day

```
db.purchases.aggregate([
    {$match: {createdAt: {$gte: new Date(2014, 0, 1)}}},
    {$group: {_id: {year : {$year :'$createdAt'},
                    month: {$month :'$createdAt'}
                    day: {$dayOfMonth: '$createdAt'}
                    },
              count: {$sum: 1}
            }
])
```

You can try to limit the documents by adjusting the $match so it returns you purchases only from last 30 days.

If you would like to group the results by month, remove the "day" from the id.